# complete graph as an union of bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, induction, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of the theorem that says

> The complete graph $K_n$ can be expressed as the union of $k$ bipartite graphs if and only if $n\leq2^k$

using the mathematical induction . Graph Theory by West gives the proof but I don't understand it. I need some one help me to understand it and simplify the proof step by step

Answer (score 3):

I think the result should be $n\leq 2^k$. Suppose $K_n$ is a union of $k$ bipartite graphs $G_1,...,G_k$. Each of the $G_i$ gives a $2$-colouring of the vertices (say red/blue). For each vertex $v$, look at the set $R_v=\{i:v\text{ red in }G_i\}$. Now $R_v\neq R_w$, since there is an edge between $v$ and $w$ in some $G_i$, and then they have different colours in that $G_i$, so $i$ is in exactly one of the sets. There are $2^k$ possible sets, and all $n$ sets must be different, so $n\leq 2^k$.

From an assignment of sets to vertices where all vertices get different sets, you can work backwards to construct the $G_i$.

Comment: what is the Rv set and how they are 2^k possible set ?    also can we use mathematical induction to prove it ( how to use induction to prove an if and only if statement ) ?

Comment: The point is that you look at the colours of a vertex in the $k$ different bipartite graphs. For each graph you have two possible colours (because bipartite), so overall there are $2^k$ different choices.But if two vertices have exactly the same choices, then they aren't adjacent in any of the $G_i$, which is impossible if their union is $K_n$.

Comment: You could use induction (although I don't see why you'd want to). You'd need two different inductions though: i) prove that you can express $K_{2^k}$ as a union of $k$ bipartite graphs; ii) prove that you can't express $K_{2^k+1}$ as a union of $k$ bipartite graphs. Both of these can be done by induction, and that's sufficient because if you can express $K_n$ as such a union, you can also express $K_{n-1}$ just by removing vertex $n$ from all the graphs.

Comment: Ok , But why all n sets must be different and i is exactly one of the set ? can you add the backward proof step by step may i can understand it better . Also I thought it solved only with induction But it is clear that your proof is better .

Comment: can we use induction by assume that P(k-1) true and try to prove that p(k) true where P(k) is the theorem depending on k the number of bipartite graph . Is that true ? if it is can you help me doing this proof by this idea of induction ?

Comment: Do you have any idea about proving it with induction ?

Comment: To do it by induction: to show i), it's obvious for $k=1$; suppose you can do $K_{2^k}$ with $k$ bipartite graphs, then you can do two copies of $K_{2^k}$ with $k$ (disconnected) bipartite graphs, then connect them together with another bipartite graph to make $K_{2^{k+1}}$.

Comment: To show ii), again it's obvious for $k=1$ (you can't make $K_3$ with one bipartite graph). Suppose it's true for $k$. If you can make $K_{2^{k+1}+1}$ with $k+1$ bipartite graphs, remove any one of them. Now prove that whatever is left must contain a complete graph on at least $2^k+1$ vertices. But this can't be covered with the remaining $k$ bipartite graphs, contradiction.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime i was searching for an explanation for this problem and ur solution truly deserves respect .. thanks much