# Combining probability and binary system in a combinatorics problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binary

This question is not so difficult but I have been quite fascinated with the way it was solved. It is stated as follow:

> Given n students participating in a contest of m questions. At each stage, a student may choose to do the question in English or German or skip it. For every two questions, there exists a student who chooses to do both the questions and do them in different languages. What is the largest value that m can take

> **Hint**: The answer to this question is $m \le 2^n$, you might expect where the binary system is used

I solved this problem, using mathematical induction. However, the solution using probability simply looks better! Any solution is appreciated!

Comment: This question is a restating of [Complete graph as an union of bipartite graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2178906/177399)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution with binary sequences and the pigeonhole principle.

Imagine a table whose rows are indexed by the $m$ questions, the columns are indexed by the $n$ students, and the entry for question $q$ and student $p$ is determined as follows:

- If $p$ did not answer $q$, or $p$ answered $q$ in English, then the entry is $0$.
- If $p$ answered $q$ in German, then entry is $1$.

Each question $q$ now has a row of $0$'s and $1$'s associated with it. I claim that any two different questions must have different binary sequences. Indeed, for every pair of questions, there exists a student whose answered one question in English and the other in German, implying one of the sequences has a $0$ in that place and other as a $1$.

Since there are $2^n$ possible binary sequences, and each of the $m$ questions has a different one, it must be the case that $m\le 2^n$. (This can be seen as an application of the pigeonhole principle; if you assumed $m\ge 2^n+1$, then having the questions be pigeons and the sequences be pigeonholes, then you would have two pigeons in the same hole, contradicting what was established before).

Comment: Oh no, if there are two questions, and the entries are $(a_1,a_2,...a_{j-1}, not chosen, a{j+1},...,a_n)$ and $(a_1,a_2,...a_{j-1}, German, a{j+1},...,a_n)$ then this is still counted as wrong. I mean, no choice doesn't count equal to English though. You've got the idea, just a bit of fixing

Comment: @NikolaTolzsek The situation you describe does not invalidate my proof (not sure if you were saying that). It is true that "no choice ≠ English", but for the purposes of this proof, it is helpful to consider these as equivalent. Only the distinction between English and German is necessary to probe that all rows must be distinct. Furthermore, if you recorded "no choice" as different than "English," you would only prove that $m\le 3^n$, so this trick is necessary.

Comment: That's why it would be more difficult than you thought and should use more than a binary system! Yet another hint: if you denote a question not chosen (-1), find a way to convert a sequence with (-1) it to some sequences of 0 and 1 only. Only then your answer is valid!

Comment: @NikolaTolzsek You said "find a way to convert a sequence with $-1$ to something with $0$ and $1$ only." My method was to change all $-1$'s to $0$ (which is equivalent to recording "didn't answer" as "0" in the first place). Are you saying this does not work? If so, can you please tell me your method?